# How does Xcode sets rootViewController implicitly via storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Xcode with the **project file** and **Info.plist** locates the main.storyboard and finds out the initial ViewController. But I was hoping to see some boiler plate code in AppDelegate for the ViewController.

**AppDelegate** looks blank: (**No reference to ViewController**)

```
@implementation AppDelegate    
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  return YES;
}

...

@end
```

**StoryBoard** is xml:
[image]

**Question**

Does Xcode what **magic** code to refer **storyboard xml** and find the controller ?

**After the compilation**, main() brings up AppDelegate which should either have reference to ViewController directly or have a proxy storyboard object to get to the ViewController.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I think this question add value and the answers are amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my book (which you already found) explains it fully. `main` calls `UIApplicationMain()` and it follows certain rules. If you have a main storyboard designated in your Info.plist — and you do — then:

- `UIApplication` pulls the *initial view controller* instance (the one with the Entry Point arrow) out of the storyboard. That's the ViewController instance.
- It also instantiates the UIApplication class.
- It also instantiates the app delegate class (specified in the `UIApplicationMain` call), and assigns it to the UIApplication's `delegate` property.
- It makes a window and assigns it to the app delegate's `window` property, then assigns that view controller to the window's `rootViewController` property.
- Then it shows the window (and calls `applicationDidFinishLaunching...` on the app delegate`).

That completely explains the launch process.

Comment: Hi matt, which book are you referring to. I would love to learn about how the dots connect at least at a high level.

This explanation was really helpful. I find all the explanation about certain classes but not much about how does Xcode implicitly plays a role in the app.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch06.html Stop saying Xcode. Xcode plays no role. You compile and build with Xcode. You run on the runtime. The runtime is doing this. You know, Cocoa. You call UIApplicationMain and _that is what it does_. I don't see why this is hard. You've been told three times now by three different people.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, Xcode is just building. Interface builder based on the storyboards seem magical at first and the UI is provided by Xcode so it seems like its Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

A picture is worth a thousand words.. However, here's a short description: "It's in your project's settings/info.plist".

In the picture below "Main" is the name of my initial storyboard. Also, initial view controllers have a flag in the interface builder that says "Is Initial View Controller" to tell it that's the view controller you wish to run first.

P.S. Clicking on the images enlarges them :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Brandon, this is really helpful and to some extend answers the question.
I want to understand what is the flow of control during build.

It looks like Info.plist is the manifest for the app. Where can I read about how does xcode navigates through the app architecture to compile the app ?

Comment: XCode is just an IDE/Build system. Clang is the compiler it uses to compile your app.

Comment: Found this http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch06.html explaining a little deeper. (Was helpful)

Comment: Question still remains, since xcode is just the IDE/Build system. Why don't we see ViewController in AppDelegate ?

I would have assumed Xcode can auto-wire things in the template app for us to expand on. At the end of the day main() is the entry point which invokes AppDelegate - There must be something in AppDelegate that knows about ViewController ?

Comment: I have updated the question to better reflect the question.

Comment: `AppDelegate.window.rootViewController` will be the initial view controller IF you remove it from Info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the dynamic nature of Objective-C allows `UIApplicationMain()` to bootstrap your application solely from the textual information stored in your application's `info.plist` file and your main NIB or main Storyboard.  There's no need for the compiler to generate boilerplate code.

The longer answer:

UIApplicationMain does the following things to through the Objective-C runtime:

- In all cases, `UIApplicationMain()` instantiates the `NSPrincipalClass` key in your plist, typically `UIApplication` but can be a custom subclass.
- In an old-style NIB-less application, `UIApplicationMain()` will instantiate the AppDelegate class that was specified in `main.m`.  It will wire the AppDelegate to `UIApplication`, and then hand off to the AppDelegate to create the app window, root view controller, etc.
- In a NIB-based application, `UIApplicationMain` does not know the name of the AppDelegate.  Instead, it loads your main NIB file `NSMainNibFile`, as specified in the plist.  The NIB is responsible for instantiating your AppDelegate and wiring to UIApplication, along with creating your main window and root view controller.
- In a Storyboard application, `UIApplicationMain` instantiates the `NSPrincipalClass` and the app delegate as specified in main.m, just like a NIB-less application.  It then loads the main storyboard, which knows who the initial view controller is.  It creates a window, instantiates the initial view controller, and assigns it as the root view controller for the window.

Comment: Wow great explanation of the 3 generations of app launch process :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason behind it :-

[image]

and if you remove that mark You'll get a blank screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I was wondering how does AppDelegate get to know about it. Xcode is just an IDE.

Comment: I don't think i can explain the process behind that due to the fact I'm also a beginner and learning but maybe this will trigger some methods that create methods for initial view . @YugalJindle